# Efficient byte by float multiplication

Tags: python, algorithm, python-3.x

On the input I have a signed array of bytes `barr` (usually little endian, but that probably doesn't matter) and a float `f` to multiply `barr` with.

My approach is to convert `barr` into an integer `val` (using `int.from_bytes` function), multiply it, perform overflow checks and "crop" multiplied `val` if needed, then convert it back into an array of bytes.

```
def multiply(barr, f):
        val = int.from_bytes(barr, byteorder='little', signed=True)
        val *= f
        val = int (val)
        val = cropInt(val, bitLen = barr.__len__()*8)
        barr = val.to_bytes(barr.__len__(), byteorder='little', signed=True)
        return barr

def cropInt(integer, bitLen, signed = True):
        maxValue = (2**(bitLen-1)-1) if signed else (2**(bitLen)-1)
        minValue = -maxValue-1 if signed else 0
        if integer > maxValue:
            integer = maxValue
        if integer < minValue:
            integer = minValue
        return integer
```

However this process is extremely slow when processing a large amount of data. Is there a better, more efficient way to do that?

Comment: Try to use [struct](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html) module to parse bytes sequnces. Also you can remove `maxValue` and `minValue` calculation from `cropInt` function to increase its speed.

Comment: Unfortunately each array of bytes might be of different length thus I need to count it every time (but since they are mostly of the same length, I could build a short-term memory for the computation).

Comment: From a quick `timeit` session, most of the time is spent for `int.from_bytes()` and `int.to_bytes()`, which will be difficult to make faster

Comment: Did you mean more *efficient*?

Comment: Yes, sorry. Post and its title edited

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pure Python is rather innefective for any numeric calculations - because due to each number being treated as an object, each operation involves a lot of "under the hood" steps.

On the other hand, Python can be very effective for numeric calculation if you use the appropriate set of third party libraries.

In your case, sice performance matters, you can make use of [`NumPy`](http://www.numpy.org/) - the de facto Python package for numeric processing.

With it the casting, multiplication and recasting will be done in native code in one pass each (and after knowing better NumPy than I do, probably with even less steps) - and should give you an improvement of 3-4 orders of magnitude in speed for this task:

```
import numpy as np
def multiply(all_bytes, f, bitlen, signed=True): 

    # Works for 8, 16, 32 and 64 bit integers:
    dtype = "%sint%d" % ("" if signed else "",   bitlen)
    max_value = 2 ** (bitlen- (1 if signed else 0)) - 1

    input_data = np.frombuffer(all_bytes, dtype=dtype)
    processed = np.clip(input_data * f, 0, max_value)
    return bytes(processed.astype(dtype))
```

Please not this example takes all your byte-data at once, not one at a time as you pass to your original "multiply" function. Threfore, you also have to pass it the size in bits of your integers.

The line that goes `dtype = "%sint%d" % ("" if signed else "",   bitlen)` creates the data-type name, as used by NumPy from the number of bits passed in. SInce the name is just a string, it interpolates a string adding or not an "u" prefix, depending on the datatype being unsigned, and put the number of bits at the end. NumPy datatypes can be checked at: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.types.html

Running with an array of 500000 8bit signed integers I get these timings:

In [99]: %time y = numpy_multiply(data, 1.7, 8)
CPU times: user 3.01 ms, sys: 4.96 ms, total: 7.97 ms
Wall time: 7.38 ms

In [100]: %time x = original_multiply(data, 1.7, 8)
CPU times: user 11.3 s, sys: 1.86 ms, total: 11.3 s
Wall time: 11.3 s

(That is after modifying your function to operate on all bytes at a time as well) - an speedup of 1500 times, as I've stated on the first draft.

Comment: FYI, this does not produce the same result as OP method. (but I don't know why...)

Comment: And it is actually _slower_ than OP method

Comment: Sorry - this can't possibily be slower than the OP method - but if you are trying with a single number at a time - this takes the whole amount of data the OP needs at once.

Comment: I want to believe you, but timeit says otherwise :) : with arbitrary `my_bytes = b"1EZR3"` and `my_float = 8.0`, I get 5.972544721647864 for yours and 3.836732462648797 for OP. But I am not able to get an explanation for that difference.

Comment: 1000000 times, the np import is obviously _not_ included in the loop

Comment: No -  put 1000000 bytes in the function call, not "5" bytes in the function call.

Comment: @Gullaume -anyway, thanks for commenting - it was indeed wrong in that the OP is clipping the values, and I was just truncating the most-fsignificative bytes after multiplying.

Comment: I made the same test with `my_bytes = b"1EZR3"*10000` , I get 138.9779563455486 for you and `OverflowError: int too large to convert to float` on `val *= f` for OP. With `my_bytes = b"1EZR3"*10`, I get 12.382181490880612 for you and 4.78680513379004 for OP (so OP scales better until he reaches float limit)

Comment: Sorry - you are still unable to use the function I've passed. (I've put an incorec version before the fixed one now) .  If you can't see it, the OP's function works one number at a time, while the example with NumPy I've provided will multiply all his data.


I am appending a quck benchmark for 500000 8bit numbers at the answer now -

Comment: Thank you all for helping me and testing the run times. I appreciate the spirit of this site a lot.  However I don't quite understand this piece of code: `dtype = "%sint%d" % ("" if signed else "",   bitlen)`, what does it mean?

Comment: I've added a paragraph on the answer to explain this line now.

Comment: Shouldn't it be like `dtype = "%sint%d" % ("" if signed else "u", bitlen)` then?

Comment: Also it is necessary to also compute `min_value = -max_value - 1` and replace 0 in `np.clip(input_data * f, 0, max_value)` by `min_value` since in your implementation -100*0.2 is always set to zero.

Comment: Did you mean *inefficient* in your first sentence?